# complexification of $SO(2)$

Tags: lie-groups

While computing the complexification of Lie group $SO(2)$, I get the result is all the matrix of the following form 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{e^{t-\sqrt{-1}\theta}+e^{-t+\sqrt{-1}\theta}}{2} & \frac{e^{-t+\sqrt{-1}\theta}-e^{t-\sqrt{-1}\theta}}{2\sqrt{-1}} \\
-\frac{e^{-t+\sqrt{-1}\theta}-e^{t-\sqrt{-1}\theta}}{2\sqrt{-1}}& \frac{e^{t-\sqrt{-1}\theta}+e^{-t+\sqrt{-1}\theta}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
for $t$ and $\theta$ are both real numbers. I want to know what are this matrices like, or there is another description. Specially $SO(2)$ can act on $\mathbb{C}$ as a rotation? How could its complexification acts on $\mathbb{C}$ naturally?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the map $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}\rightarrow SO_2(\mathbb{C})$ given by
$$
t\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{t+t^{-1}}{2} & \frac{i(t-t^{-1})}{2} \cr
-\frac{i(t-t^{-1})}{2} &  \frac{t+t^{-1}}{2} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is a group isomorphism. So we have a simple description.

Comment: Ah Sulfur Dioxide! Wait...

Comment: Yes, and even $S+O_2=SO_2$ is quite OK.

Comment: Oh! That is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a while so I just wanted to complement Dietrich's answer with a way of coming up with this isomorphism.

The way that I found natural is to note that the vector representation of $SO(2,\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is not irreducible. In fact, following the technique suggested in [Decompose the representation $V$ of $SO_2$ into irreducible representations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767563/decompose-the-representation-v-of-so-2-into-irreducible-representations), one sees that it splits into a direct sum of 1-dimensional irreducible representations $\mathbb{C}^2=V_+\oplus V_-$. On $V_{\pm}=\text{span}_\mathbb{C}\{(1,\mp i)\}$ an element of the form $e^{aJ}\in SO(2,\mathbb{C})$, with
$$J=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
acts like $t^{\pm1}=e^{\pm ia}=\cos(a)+i\sin(a)\in\mathbb{C}^\times$. Moreover,
$$e^{aJ}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(a) & -\sin(a)\\ \sin(a) & \cos(a)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{t+t^{-1}}{2} & -\frac{t-t^{-1}}{2i}\\\frac{t+t^{-1}}{2i} & \frac{t+t^{-1}}{2} \end{pmatrix}$$