# How is $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ the complexification of $SU(2)$?

Tags: lie-groups, unitary-matrices

I am learning about complexification of real Lie groups. From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification_(Lie_group)), I see that I have a lot to learn.

I learned from [my earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275149/how-are-sun-sln-and-mathfraksln-mathbbc-related) that the real Lie group $SU(n)$ is a real form of $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$, or in other words, $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the complexification of $SU(n)$.

For the corresponding Lie algebras I verified that given $C\in \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ I can find $A,B\in \mathfrak{su}(n)$ such that $C=A+iB$. And similarly, if $A,B\in \mathfrak{su}(n)$, then $A+iB \in \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$. Which I understand to mean that $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})=\mathfrak{su}(n) \bigoplus \mathfrak{su}(n)$, and, in fact, $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})=\mathfrak{su}(n) \bigotimes \mathbb{C}$.

But as regards the Lie groups, I fail to similarly break down a special linear matrix $C\in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ into two special unitary matrices $A,B\in SU(2)$. For example, when I solve:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ -b^* & a^*\end{pmatrix} + i \begin{pmatrix}c & d\\ -d^* & c^*\end{pmatrix}$$
I get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{1}{2} & 1\end{pmatrix} + i \begin{pmatrix}0 & -i\frac{1}{2}\\ -i\frac{1}{2} & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
The last two matrices are in $U(2)$ but not in $SU(2)$ because their determinants are not equal to $1$.

So there is something more subtle going on here with the complexification.

Please, as concretely as possible, how does complexification of $SU(2)$ yield $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$? Additionally,  I am curious what this example could help me understand in the Wikipedia article. Thank you!

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like this that was done for SO(2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970019/complexification-of-so2?rq=1

Comment: You are using a wrong definition of the complexification of a Lie group in your computations (you should not **add** elements of a group!).

Comment: @Moishe-Kohan, your comment is helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to read https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf to learn about the complexification process

Comment: @Weier Thank you! That looks very relevant and helpful for me.